# Azure DevOps Release Task SQL table - looking for all servers we copy to

Tags: azure-devops, release

We have azure devops 2019 1.1.  I am needing to find a way to identify the servers we copy to across all projects in all releases.  Most of the time we just use the copy file task and do something like copy to \servename\inetput\site.  Is there a table I can look at and see all the tasks in all releases and grab that data?

Comment: Hi Does these APIs work for you or do you have other better solutions for this issue that can share it here, which can help others who encounter the same issue in the future? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that currently there is no such tables with this feature as this is a custom requirement.

As a workaround, if you directly use the specific value as the target folder for the [Copy Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), you could use this Rest API: [Definitions - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) to list all release definitions and use Rest API: [Definitions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) get single release definition details. And then search the [Copy Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), whose task id is 5bfb729a-a7c8-4a78-a7c3-8d717bb7c13c. And then find the value of `TargetFolder` argument.

If you use variable as the target folder, you will have to further use Rest API: [Releases - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) to get a list of releases for single release definition. And then use Rest API: [Releases - Get Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) to get single release details. And then search the [Copy Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) via its task id. And then find the value of `TargetFolder` argument.

I have to say that this workaround takes lots of work, it is not easier than manually check the releases via web portal.